# How do I configure nginx to forward the request to some gateway servr which sends the response to client

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to process the request in django and add custom header to the request and let the nginx to forward the request to some gateway server resides on another machine.

I attempted few trails, but doesn't seem it is working.

Came across the proxy_pass which does pretty much same stuff, but sends the request to a specified proxied server, fetches the response, and sends it back to the client. I don't wish to get back the response to my nginx server and let the gateway server send the response directly to the client.

I would like to get the request from nginx server and do pretty authentication, and add custom header to the request and forward to the gateway server which performs the logic and sends the response back to client directly.

**Here is the code:**

*Django view*

```
response = Response()
   # response['User-Information'] = user.username
   response['X-Accel-Redirect']='/route/'
   return response
```

*Nginx conf.*

```
 upstream gateway {

     server 192.168.1.45:3000;
    }
location /route {

    proxy_pass  http://gateway/postdata;
    proxy_method POST;
   }
```

Comment: Read it https://wellfire.co/learn/nginx-django-x-accel-redirects/. It might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have been through the blog but things doesn't work out that way.